# Gmail retrive body text cwoth out b'..\r\n exmaple b'message1\r\n'

Tags: python, list, email, gmail, fetch

WIth this script i'd like to retreive messages from gmdail.

The expected output of the script should be `message1, message2, message3, message4, message5`

But the script print out the following list `[b'message1\r\n', b'message2\r\n', b'message3\r\n', b'message4\r\n', b'message5\r\n']`

Does anyone can help me on this?
Here is the code snippet:

```
import imaplib

def read_gmail():
    # user and pass for login to gmail server
    username = input("Enter Email Address for Login: ").lower()
    password = input("Enter password for Login: ").lower()

    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)

    if username == "me" and password == "me":
        mail.login('mymail', 'mypass')
    else:
        mail.login(username, password)

    mail.list()
    mail.select("Inbox")

    status, data = mail.search(None, 'SUBJECT "Enc Message"')  # all message with Subject-> Enc Message
    minimata = [] 
    clear_lista = []

    for num in data[0].split():
        status, data = mail.fetch(num, '(BODY.PEEK[TEXT])')  # to see the body text
        
        minimata.append(data[0][1])  # apothikeyo se nea lista ta kryprografimena minimata.
        
    for ch in minimata:
        clear_lista.append(ch)

    return clear_lista
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `minimata` list contains byte objects and this is where the leading `b'` comes from. To get rid of them you just need to decode them.

Regarding, `\n` and `\r`, you can use `rstrip()`.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
for ch in minimata:
    clear_lista.append(ch.rstrip().decode())
```